# Collapse mãe fechar o collapse filho também, porém não abrir junto no bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico no `collapse mãe` "Segurança":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abriu o `collpase mãe` e dentro dele tem o `collapse filho` "Usuarios", vamos clicar no `collapse filho` "Usuarios":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui está tudo conforme eu gostaria, se o clicar para fechar o `collapse filho` "Usuarios" vai fechar normalmente, até ai está 100%.

Porém meu problema é caso clicar no `collapse mãe` "Segurança", ai vai fechar apenas o `collapse mãe` "Segurança" e o `collapse filho` vai continuar aberto, da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia fazer pra quando clicar no `collapse mãe` "Segurança", fechar também o `collapse filho` "Usuarios"?

Vale ressaltar que quando clicar para ABRIR o `collapse mãe` "Segurança", o `collapse filho` "Usuarios" não é pode abrir também, tem que ficar do seguinte jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Códigos do meu menu:

```
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="home.php"><img src="img/store2.png"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menuVertical" id="accordion">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-1">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i><span>Produtos<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul id="submenu-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span> Novo</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-edit"></i><span> Editar</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span> Pesquisar</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-2">
                <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i><span>Parâmetros<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul id="submenu-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search-minus"></i><span> Estoque Mínimo</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i><span>Relatórios</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-3">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i><span>Segurança<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul id="submenu-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-31"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span> Usuários<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span></a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="subsubmenu">
                <ul id="submenu-31" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span> Novo</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-edit"></i><span> Editar</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span> Pesquisar</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deslogar">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span>Sair</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Consegui" fazer do seguinte modo:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-3">
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i><span>Segurança<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
    </a>
</li>
<div class="submenu">
    <ul id="submenu-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-31"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span> Usuários<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span></a></li>
        <div class="subsubmenu">
            <ul id="submenu-31" class="collapse">
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span> Novo</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-edit"></i><span> Editar</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span> Pesquisar</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>           
</div>
```

Coloquei a `<div class="subsubmenu">` que contem o `collapse filho` "Usuarios" dentro da `<div class="submenu">` e também dentro da `<ul id="submenu-3" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">`, assim, quando o clicar pra fechar o `collapse mãe` "Segurança", vai fechar ele inteiro, o `collapse filho` "Usuarios" não irá fechar, porém irá "sumir", uma vez que o `collapse mãe` "Segurança" estará fechado.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel como vc está usando o JS padrão do Bootstrap acho que uma solução apenas com CSS pode te servir.

**OBS:** Precisei retirar as `<div class="submenu">` e `<div class="subsubmenu">` para a regra CSS poder ser usada. Mas vc pode criar as classes dessas divs direto nas `<ul>` com os submenus

```css
li.collapsed + ul {
  height: 0 !important;
}
li.collapsed + ul + ul.collapsed.collapse.in {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="home.php"><img src="img/store2.png"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menuVertical" id="accordion">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-1">
                <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i><span>Produtos<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul id="submenu-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span> Novo</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-edit"></i><span> Editar</span></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span> Pesquisar</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-2">
                <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i><span>Parâmetros<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <div class="submenu">
            <ul id="submenu-2" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search-minus"></i><span> Estoque Mínimo</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i><span>Relatórios</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-3">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i><span>Segurança<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        
            <ul id="submenu-3" class="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-31" data-parent="#accordion">
                <li >
                  <a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span> Usuários<i class="fa fa-angle-down float-right"></i></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            
                <ul id="submenu-31" class="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span> Novo</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="far fa-edit"></i><span> Editar</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span> Pesquisar</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            
        

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

        <li>
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deslogar">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i><span>Sair</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <!--************************************************************************************-->

    </ul>
</div>
```

Acredito que manipulando o JS original ou criando um novo Script vc consiga também, mas ai pode interferir em outros componentes que usarem o sistema de collapse do Bootstrap.